# Azure devops pipeline: how to make agent finish current build before moving to the next

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-extensions

PR to main trigger a pipeline with 2 jobs, first job build time 18 min.
When opening another PR the agent 'jump' to the other build before finishing the second job in the current build.

[image]

This is causing a delay.

Any idea how can we change the setting so the agent will do one build at a time?

note:

- We only have one agent.
- Yes, we can merge the 2 jobs into one, but the pipeline will be less readable.
- Same problem when triggering build manually.

Comment: Can I check something: is it the pipeline triggered by a PR as part of your branch policy? And the pipeline is getting cancelled when you push new changes to the source branch? Or is the situation something different?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what "we receive another PR" means here.

Comment: Hey Vince. the pipelien triggered by PR as part of branch policy. the pipeline does not get cancelled when I push new changes -> but the build is expired, so I have to re-queue it. 'we receive another PR' mean if another developer open another PR to the main branch.

Comment: So at the moment when the agent is busy running a pipeline A for PR 1, and you create PR 2, what exactly does the agent do? Does it cancel pipeline A? Or does it leave it in limbo? Or does it keep running it, but also start running pipeline B?

Comment: When PR 1 is running: The agent will finish job 1 -> then job 2 will be on queue. it will go to build number 2 (PR 2), run job 1 -> put job 2 on queue. then go back to build number 1 ->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you want to make agent finish current build before moving to the next.

I suggest that you can use the [Exclusive Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&preserve-view=true&tabs=check-pass#exclusive-lock) in YAML Pipeline.

> The exclusive lock check allows only a single run from the pipeline to proceed. All stages in all runs of that pipeline that use the resource are paused. When the stage using the lock completes, then another stage can proceed to use the resource. Also, only one stage will be allowed to continue.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create an Environment in **Pipelines -> Environments** and add Exclusive Lock. Or you can create Variable Group or other protected resources and add the Exclusive Lock.

[image]

Step2: Add the protected resources in your YAML Pipeline and set the lockBehavior.

YAML example:

```
stages:
- stage: A
  lockBehavior: sequential
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    steps:
    - script: xxx
```

When you set the lockBehavior as sequential, the Pipeline runs will run sequentially.

Comment: Hey, when I go to pipeline -> environment -> new environment there is no option for lockBehavior.. only none, k8s and vm..

Comment: You can add Approvals and checks , then you can find the Exclusive Lock. Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass. You can create an empty env and add the Exclusive Lock

Comment: @LinuxDev Is there any update about this ticket? Can Exclusive Lock  work for you?

Comment: not sure yet, we haven't had a chance to test it. but from the reading I did it should work, so this is a solution for me.